# ToggleButton disable setting IsChecked behavior on button clicked

Tags: .net, xaml, togglebutton

Is there anyway to remove the behavior of setting `IsChecked` attribute of a `ToggleButton` when I click the toggle button? I want the `IsChecked` attribute to be handled by binding to a custom property.

Comment: Just to make sure I understand correctly, you don't want it to update ischecked when it's clicked, but instead want it to only update ischecked via binding?

Comment: Yes, I want to update IsChecked only via binding and onClick's IsChecked is interfering with my bindings

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you want the control to only handle its `IsChecked` state via your binding and disallow input from the user. You could set `IsEnabled="False" but then it will appear a bit opaque in the`Disabled` state unless you alter the control template accordingly.

I think what you want would be more of a way to just omit the user input but still handle your `IsChecked` so I would suggesting setting it like;

```
<ToggleButton IsHitTestVisible="False" IsTabStop="False" IsChecked="{Binding blah}"/>
```

Hope this helps, cheers.

Comment: But now the click does not trigger his code anymore.

Comment: @Martin read his comments where I asked him to clarify that.. ;)

Comment: Thanks! I didn't think of this, however, this still disables the mouse over effect which I think I can manipulate with a little styling.

Comment: Ah I figured you were just trying to use it as like a static display and didn't consider including mouseover if it's not accepting clicks anymore anyway. If that's the case I'd probably have to think of a different way, but if it works for you and the problem is solved then that's cool. Cheers

Comment: @Chris W.: I assumed he wanted to process the click, update his viewmodel (maybe validate), and have the view strictly obeying the viewmodel state - without a view control that's deciding on its own to change its state :)

Comment: @Martin Ya I would have assumed that too, so asked for clarification in case the title/question was being misinterpreted. However in UX it's a pretty common occurrence to use things like ToggleButton/CheckBox etc as just a static display of a boolean cue to show something on/off or what have you, I've used the technique multiple times also so figured that must be the purpose, no worries.

Answer (score 1):

I know this question is pretty old but I think my answer could help someone.

So my problem is related to navigation toggle buttons. I have set `IsChecked` property to `true` in my code and the related view is showing but the design of ToggleButton was changing when user pressed it (while the view was staying the same). So eventually I had the view showing but ToggleButton was unchecked and `IsChecked` property behind was set to `true`. Totally insane.

To deal with this I made my own very simple custom control:

```
class CustomToggleButton : ToggleButton
{
    protected override void OnToggle()
    {
        if (IsChecked != true)
        {
            base.OnToggle();
        }
    }
}
```

Now ToggleButton is unchecking only from my code.

Answer (score 1):

Nice solution Chris W. Thank you! If someone still want to be able to check by clicking a button but prevent unchecking from the UI:

```
<Style TargetType="ToggleButton" x:Key="MyToggle">
  <Style.Triggers>
    <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True">
      <!-- Prevents unchecking -->
      <Setter Property="IsHitTestVisible" Value="False"/>
      <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="False"/>
    </Trigger>
  </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```